# How to get the mending enchantment?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a skeleton farm and I enchanted DOZENS of items already. I never saw "mending" though. The [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting) says, that you find this on the lower enchanting levels, but I never saw it.

Note: (Normally) Before I enchant an item, I look through all of them and check on each what I would get: Helmet, Chestplate, Leggings, Boots, Sword, Bow. I think chances that I really never could have seen it are pretty low.

Can you get this enchantment only from the end and from books? I saw some enchanted items in the end cities with mending.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mending is a **treasure enchantment**, which you can only find in the world, you can **not** create it yourself on an enchanting table.

Treasure enchantments can be obtained by

- Fishing
- Chests in dungeons, temples, mineshafts, End cities etc.
- Trading (villagers charge double price for treasure enchantments)

Mending can be found on many items, including, for example, Fishing Rods.

*Sources: [1.9 changelog](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.9), [enchantment mechanics](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchantment_mechanics#Step_Two_-_Find_possible_enchantments), [trading](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading#cite_note-book-1.8-2) pages.*

Comment: Wow. Can i fish anywhere for that?

Comment: @TrudleR Yes, fishing does not depend on location, you can fish in a 1-meter block in your base (though it is hard not to hit a block with your bobber). Fishing speed only depends on weather, sky sight (fish outside during rain for maximum efficiency) and Lure enchantment. Drop rates depend on Luck of the Sea enchantment and Potions of Luck (uncraftable in 1.9).

Comment: @OrcJMR I thought a pond had to be at least a certain depth in order to fish. Or is that something added by certain mod packs?

Comment: @Nzall nope. The bobber must only be in water. Just tested with a single block of water in 18w03a - absolutely no problem, the bobber doesn't even get stuck in the floor! The only downside is that you can't see the particles of approaching fish - but the depth of 1 m is totally fine.

Comment: If you plan to obtain Mending through plain old normal fishing, you'll need saint's patience. It's a rare drop (enchanted book is a rare drop in fishing and Mending is one of many, many enchanted books you can find) - and fishing is slow enough by itself. You may look up AFK fishing farms, to make it even somewhat viable method, Finding (or breeding!) a villager with this trade is the best, most sustainable method of obtaining multiple Mending books.

Answer (score -7):

It is possible to get mending from an enchantment table, but it is very hard and I would suggest having a very good xp farm as well as using books if you want to get it from an enchantment table. I know people say that it’s a treasure enchantment and you can’t get it from an enchantment table, but I did. Also, before anyone asks, yes, I am sure I got it from an enchantment table.

Comment: This is very simply incorrect.

Comment: The minecraft wiki specifically says that Mending is a Treasure Enchantment, meaning that it CANNOT be made in an Enchanting table