# Can I make any librarian give a mending book?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a zombie spawner which occasionally gives me zombie villagers. I've tamed a fletcher but I need more mending books so am wondering if I can get all librarians to give me mending books or its jst abt luck

Comment: Mending Book? What are you talking about?

Comment: @Jim Jones am asking if all librarioans give mending books coz I need to have it on all my armour

Answer (score 2):

It is random what ench books villagers have. Unless you use cheats, you cannot GUARANTEE a mending book. And no, not all librarians give mending books. If they do, they charge double.

Also maybe kinda duplicate-ishy thingy?

You could have looked it up --> [How to get the mending enchantment?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/260525/how-to-get-the-mending-enchantment)